# Does automatic drivers download in Windows even work?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

There is this feature in Windows 7: *Search automatically for updated driver software*. I have used it in hope that Windows will automatically find ADB drivers for Android-based phone. Unfortunately, everything I get is *Windows was unable to install your ADB*.

From what I remember this feature has never worked for me, even in times of Windows XP.

To make it a real question (and not only a complain):

- How to make Windows to automatically download a driver? (e.g. Is there something that needs to be turned on somewhere in *Control Panel*?)

Comment: One second. What's ADB?

Comment: ADB is "Android Debug Bridge" - this is helpful when you are developing applications for Android phones.

Comment: Aren't ADB drivers a part of the SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it works – as long as the manufacturer has submitted the drivers to Windows Update.**

If the manufacturer hasn't done so (for example, they almost never submit drivers for debug/reflash interfaces), then it's not like Windows can just download the first result from Google...

---

To see a complete list of what's available through **Windows Update**, visit the [**Microsoft Update Catalog**](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com) site in IE, install the ActiveX control and search for ADB drivers:

[image: 1]

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer. Maybe you know if there is a list of devices that have drivers published on Windows Update?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a full list (although there used to be). Look for "WHQL certified devices".

Comment: In fact, I think debug/reflash drivers cannot be on Windows Update because they wouldn't be allowed by WHQL.

Comment: @smbear: "Maybe you know if there is a list of devices that have drivers published on Windows Update?" - See updated answer above.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to start, "Devices and Printers" there could be a yellow bar at the top that asks you to enable automatic driver downloads.

However, ADB drivers for Android phones are mostly not found when doing automatic driver downloads. I had some printers, keyboards and mice where Windows found drivers by automatic download. For your ADB drivers, take a look at the manufacturers website, XDA-developers or search Google for "*devicename* ADB driver".

Comment: Installing the driver is not a problem. I only hoped that this can be done automatically by Windows - to save some mouse clicks. :) And it ended with a question here - no clicks were saved. ;)

Comment: I understand you. I had several Android devices, no ADB drivers were found automatically for any of those.